# How I can run a report with Wialon and PHP?

Tags: php

this is my code:

```
$jetta=13109352;
$sid="0a6326c67bc4462fcac1651e219c92f7";

$fec1 = strtotime('11.11.2015 00:00'); //1420930800

$fec2 = strtotime('11.11.2015 23:59'); //1420930800

$url='https://hst-api.wialon.com/wialon/ajax.html?svc=report/exec_report&
params={
    "reportResourceId":12876840,
    "reportTemplateId":1,
    "reportObjectId":13109352,
    "reportObjectSecId":0,
    "interval":{
        "from":'.$fec1.',
        "to":'.$fec2.',
        "flags":0x00
    }
}&sid='.$sid;
```

$json = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $json;

I have this error: {"error":4} ->>>> Invalid input

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
params={
    "reportResourceId":12876840,
    "reportTemplateId":1,
 "reportTemplate":null,
    "reportObjectId":13109352,
    "reportObjectSecId":0,
    "interval":{
        "from":'.$fec1.',
        "to":'.$fec2.',
        "flags":0x00
    }
}&sid='.$sid;
```

Comment: @Carlos  Is there a reason you have not accepted my answer?